# series involving $(-1)^k$

Tags: calculus

**Given the series ${a_n}$ : 
$a_n= \sum _{k=1}^{n}{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{k}}{{3}^{k}+\sqrt {k}}}$
prove that ${a_n}$ converges.**

So far this is what I've done:
I've split this into 2 sub-series: $k=2n$ and $k=2n+1$

for $(k=2n)$ I get: 
$\sum _{k=1}^{n} \left( {3}^{k}+\sqrt {k} \right) ^{-1} = 0$
(as k goes to infinity the whole series converges to 0)

for $(k=2n+1)$ I get:

$\sum _{k=1}^{n}- \left(  \left( {3}^{k} \right) ^{-1}+\sqrt {-k}
 \right) ^{-1}$ 
(which also converges to 0 as k approaches to infinity)

Since both subs-series of $a_n$ converge to the same value, $0$, $a_n$ converges, in particular to $0$.

*I'm not sure if this is a tight enough proof since maybe by chance it works out here specifically. I also checked separate limits as k approaches $-\infty$. They both converge to $0$ for each sub-series. 
What am I missing?
Thanks.*

Comment: Don't write $k=2n$ when the letter $n$ is already in use. Additionally, don't write $\sum_{k=1}^n$ if you mean to only sum over odds or evens in particular. Lastly: (a) how can a sum of positive numbers equal $0$, and (b) how are you getting *negative* $k$ in your sum over odd $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
|a_n| \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{ 1}{3^k + \sqrt k} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3^k - \frac 12 3^k} < 2 \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac 13 \right)^k
$$
which converges because this is a geometric series. Since $a_n$ converges absolutely it converges conditionally.

You could also use Leibniz's criterion, which states that if a series has leading term $(-1)^k b_k$ with $b_k \to 0$, then $\sum (-1)^k b_k$ converges. The fact that $b_k = \frac 1{3^k + \sqrt k} \to 0$ is clear enough.

EDIT : As the comments pointed out, I didn't remember at the time all the hypothesis of Leibniz's Criterion, which are that on top of what I said, the $b_k$'s must be, up to some $N$, non-negative and decreasing.

Hope that helps,

Comment: thanks, Leibniz's criterion makes this very clear. Glad to discover it.

Comment: The alternating series test (aka Leibniz criterion) applies when the terms have alternating sign, converge to zero *and are monotone decreasing* (in absolute value). This last part is essential and you can construct counterexamples if you leave it out.

Comment: It would also be good to emphasize that the $b_k$ are nonnegative (this is implied by the hypotheses that @zulon adds), since you could do something silly like $b_k = (-1)^k(1/k)$. I'm interested in seeing an example in which $0 \leq b_k \to 0$ and yet $b_k$ not being monotone messes things up.

Comment: Take $u_n = {1 \over n}$ for even $n$ and $u_n = {-1 \over 2n}$ for odd $n$. Then $u_n$ converges to zero, is alternating (but not monotone in absolute value), and $\sum u_n$ diverges. Even simpler take $u_n = {(-1)^n \over \sqrt{n} + (-1)^n}$, then $\sum u_n$ diverges (easily seen using an asymptotic expansion).

Comment: Okay guys, sorry if I didn't remember all the hypothesis. It's good that you pointed them out, but my point was mostly that you could use the criterion, not that I wanted to describe it completely.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Leibniz's Rule for alternating series.

If $\{ a_n\}$ is a monotonic decrasing sucesion of numbers, the alternate series converges, and if $S$ is the sum, then, for every $n > 0$: $$ 0 < (-1)^n (S-s_n) < a_{n+1}$$ and $$0 < S < a_1$$

Thus your series converges, and you can calculate it's sum approximately with the first inequality.